# Average Score Review System in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, range, average

I am trying to make a review center using input range sliders. They range from 1 to 10 and a number is displayed on the side of each sldier, followed by /10. A JavaScript function is used to change the number on the side of the slider to the correct number. This works perfectly.

The problems come with the average score function findaverage(). When you adjust one slider, the value displayed ([span id="averageScore"] in first [tr])ranges from the correct value to random values like 233.5, which is impossible as it is out of 10. It's even worse when a second and third slider are adjusted.

Here is the page in action: http://magnemation.com/games/review_center_test.html

I would love to see some ideas about why this is, and sorry about the indenting.
Cheers.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Design</td>
    <td>
        <input type="range" name="Design" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" onchange="showValue1(this.value)" />
        <br>
        <br>
    </td>
    <td align="right" width="22px"> <span id="Design">0</span>

    </td>
    <td align="left">/10</td>
    <td rowspan="3" align="center" width="300px">Total Score:
        <br><span id="averageScore" style="font-size: 60px;">0</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue1(newValue) {
        document.getElementById("Design").innerHTML = newValue;
        findaverage();
    }
</script>
<tr>
    <td>Functionality</td>
    <td>
        <input type="range" name="Functionality" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" onchange="showValue2(this.value)" />
        <br>
        <br>
    </td>
    <td align="right" width="22px"> <span id="Functionality">0</span>

    </td>
    <td align="left">/10</td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue2(newValue) {
        document.getElementById("Functionality").innerHTML = newValue;
        findaverage();
    }
</script>
<tr>
    <td>Ease of Use</td>
    <td>
        <input type="range" name="Ease of Use" min="0" max="10" step="0.5" onchange="showValue3(this.value)" />
        <br>
        <br>
    </td>
    <td align="right" width="22px"> <span id="Ease of Use">0</span>

    </td>
    <td align="left">/10</td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showValue3(newValue) {
        document.getElementById("Ease of Use").innerHTML = newValue;
        findaverage();
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function findaverage() {
        var total = 0;
        var average = 0;
        total += document.getElementById("Design").innerHTML;
        total += document.getElementById("Functionality").innerHTML;
        total += document.getElementById("Ease of Use").innerHTML;
        average = total / 3;
        var rounded = Math.round(average * 2) / 2;
        document.getElementById("averageScore").innerHTML = rounded;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Scadoodles answer below will get you back on the right path, but you should probably give your inputs a proper ID attribute if you want to retrieve them using getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating strings instead of adding numbers. Use parseFloat() to convert the innerHTML strings to usable numbers.

```
function findaverage() {
  var total = 0;
  var average = 0;
  total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("Design").innerHTML);
  total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("Functionality").innerHTML);
  total += parseFloat(document.getElementById("Ease of Use").innerHTML);
  average = total/3;
  var rounded = Math.round(average*2)/2;
  document.getElementById("averageScore").innerHTML=rounded;
}
```